# Android RelativeLayout Position issue when keypad is getting displayed

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I am developing an android app.I am using `RelativeLayout` for login page and adding a button at the bottom using `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`, but whenever i am type into login box keypad is getting displayed and that login button is also getting shifted above the keypad.I want that button always to remain at the bottom.

How to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` to the related activity in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
<activity android:name="MyActivity"

   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">

</activity>
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Awesome.thnks a lot.Working fine now.